# Displaying Documents With ListView Across Site Collections

Tags: web-part

Is there a way to use the SharePoint ListVeiw web part to display documents contain in a Document Center site collection?

We are not seeing a way to use this web part and point it to a Document Library located in a document center.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since almost all solutions I design go across site collection or even web application, I have pretty much abandoned list view web parts, content query web parts etc, unless for very specific purposes.
Instead I use search. Either by configuring an Out of Box search result web part with a static query, or inheriting from search result web part and creating a custom one if needed. 
All you need to do is to figure out the Keyword Query and the XSLT.

In fact we even use this approach for top navigation across site collections...

Find Keyword query syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx).
Find guidance on customizing search results [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819886.aspx)

Comment: One other alternative is to use OData (REST) via ListData.svc

Answer (score 0):

ListView web parts don't go beyond the site the list/library lives in.  If you want to see data from another site or site collection, you need to use page viewer web parts, dataview web parts or third party tools like the lightning conductor web part from lightning tools.

Comment: not sure about page viewer and DVWP, but CQWP doesn't go across site collections.

Comment: Not natively, I thought it could be extended to do so though.

Comment: no unfortunately not. It fetches data from SPSiteDataQuery which is limited to site (as the name implies;-)

Comment: I think DVWPs don't go across site collections either.

Comment: that is correct, i ment SPSite aka Site Collection :)